# Oracle TNS: No Listener error while tnsping for my service

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tns

I just Installed Oracle 11g on windows 7 64bit, and when I tried to ping using `tnsping` I faced this error `TNS-12541: TNS:no listener`.

So, I tried to start the listener using `LSNRCTL> start` also I faced this error:

```
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
```

Comment: Did you run the Network Configuration Assistant?  If so, run it to setup your tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: I found the service stopped but even after starting it I faced this error


Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
(DESCRIPTION =    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MTahaPC.lan)(PORT = 1521))    (CONNECT_DATA =      (SERVER = DEDICATED)      (SERVICE_NAME = MTAHAPC)    )  )

Comment: That means either you:edit $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora and then start the listener or take RC's suggestion which is easier.

Answer (score 3):

Set `ORACLE_HOME` and try starting the Listener again.